# MySQL - Insert text into specific table... specific position

Tags: mysql

In a table, I have a `parameters` column which basically has options for the current row:

```
inheritFrom=29
theme=
num_leading_items=2
num_leading_columns=1
leadingImgSize=Large
num_primary_items=4
num_primary_columns=2
primaryImgSize=Medium
num_secondary_items=4
num_secondary_columns=1
secondaryImgSize=Small
num_links=4
num_links_columns=1
linksImgSize=XSmall
catCatalogMode=0
catFeaturedItems=1
catOrdering=
catPagination=2
catPaginationResults=1
catTitle=1
catTitleItemCounter=1
catDescription=1
catImage=1
catFeedLink=1
subCategories=1
subCatColumns=2
subCatOrdering=
subCatTitle=1
subCatTitleItemCounter=1
subCatDescription=1
subCatImage=1
itemImageXS=
itemImageS=
itemImageM=
itemImageL=
itemImageXL=
catItemTitle=1
catItemTitleLinked=1
catItemFeaturedNotice=0
catItemAuthor=1
catItemDateCreated=1
catItemRating=0
catItemImage=1
catItemIntroText=1
catItemIntroTextWordLimit=
catItemExtraFields=0
catItemHits=0
catItemCategory=1
catItemTags=1
catItemAttachments=0
catItemAttachmentsCounter=0
catItemVideo=0
catItemVideoWidth=
catItemVideoHeight=
catItemVideoAutoPlay=0
catItemImageGallery=0
catItemDateModified=0
catItemReadMore=1
catItemCommentsAnchor=1
catItemK2Plugins=1
itemDateCreated=1
itemTitle=1
itemFeaturedNotice=1
itemAuthor=1
itemFontResizer=1
itemPrintButton=1
itemEmailButton=1
itemSocialButton=1
itemVideoAnchor=1
itemImageGalleryAnchor=1
itemCommentsAnchor=1
itemRating=1
itemImage=1
itemImgSize=Large
itemImageMainCaption=1
itemImageMainCredits=1
itemIntroText=1
itemFullText=1
itemExtraFields=1
itemDateModified=1
itemHits=1
itemTwitterLink=1
itemCategory=1
itemTags=1
itemShareLinks=1
itemAttachments=1
itemAttachmentsCounter=1
itemRelated=1
itemRelatedLimit=5
itemVideo=1
itemVideoWidth=
itemVideoHeight=
itemVideoAutoPlay=0
itemVideoCaption=1
itemVideoCredits=1
itemImageGallery=1
itemNavigation=1
itemComments=1
itemAuthorBlock=1
itemAuthorImage=1
itemAuthorDescription=1
itemAuthorURL=1
itemAuthorEmail=1
itemAuthorLatest=1
itemAuthorLatestLimit=5
itemK2Plugins=1
```

I'm trying to see if there is a way to insert a text string, essentially `feedLink=1` in-between `catFeedLink=1` and `subCategories=1`. I've used `INSERT` before, but from my research so far, I'm having a hard time grasping how to insert in-between two values. Any nudge in the right direction would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: This is content of one column in one row? Why aren't you splitting data into multiple rows/columns or at least using `serialize(...)` on the data?

Comment: This is any how bad practice...divide your table to make it manageable...

Comment: Hi, Unfortunately, not possible to alter "how" the table is done - I'm at the current mercy of Joomla! and K2 (specifically). Please see i40.tinypic.com/2s12n2c.png and i44.tinypic.com/fbgqp0.png for reference.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to change the structure of that table?

If so I suppose it makes sense to extract parameters column from that table.

Here's one of the possible approaches:

1. Create RowId column instead of parameters column.
2. Create RowParameters table: [ RowId | Parameter | Value ]

Here's some examples of RowParameters table data:

```
RowId | ParameterName | Value
1 | itemIntroText | 1
1 | catItemImage | 1
```

If you care about parameters order - just add Order (int) column. So you'll be able to sort parameters by that column.

As a next improvement you could consider to replace ParameterName with ParameterId.(by introducing Parameters table)

Comment: Hi,
Unfortunately, not possible to alter "how" the table is done - I'm at the current mercy of Joomla! and K2 (specifically). Please see http://i40.tinypic.com/2s12n2c.png and http://i44.tinypic.com/fbgqp0.png for reference.

Comment: I see... what if you'll update parameters (as required) in the code, and pass it into insert?

Comment: Ha just thought of that a second ago myself - yup, I think that'll work fine. Thanks!